# How to use "read" to enter a directory "cd" to change a file "chmod +x"?

Tags: command-line, bash

The following Bash script exits after the first `read -p` line.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo Put me next to your targeted .sh file!
read -p "Press [Enter] key when placed next to target..."

echo Type your .sh filename (target.sh)...
read target

chmod +x $target
echo Target Converted!
read -p "Press [Enter] key to Exit..."
```

Could somebody explain why the script exits and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 4):

The script exits because of the following error:

```
a.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
a.sh: line 7: `echo Type your .sh filename (target.sh)...'
```

In Bash, and more generally in command line interpreters, some characters are special and have a meaning. `(` and `)` are two of those characters.

When using `echo`, `read -p` or other similar commands, always enclose your strings in quotes, like this:

```
echo "Put me next to your targeted .sh file!"
[...]
echo "Type your .sh filename (target.sh)..."
[...]
echo "Target Converted!"
```